# I am getting NullPointerException on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView, CardView and ViewPager in a project but the app keeps crashing due to NullPointerException error. I have tried the solutions to related questions on this platform but I am still unable to fix the bug. Can someone help me look at my codes and tell me what I'm missing?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new              ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new PhoneAppsDataFragment(), "PHONE APPS DATA");
    adapter.addFragment(new SocialNetworkDataFragment(), "SOCIAL  NETWORK DATA");
    adapter.addFragment(new PersonaManagerFragment(), "PERSONA MANAGER");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<> ();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new  ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
    }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
    }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it  is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:elevation="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

PhoneAppsDataFragment.java (to implement RecyclerView and CardView)

```
public class PhoneAppsDataFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
public PhoneAppsDataFragment() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new      LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    return layout;



}

public static List<Information> getData() {
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] logos = {R.drawable.ic_number1, R.drawable.ic_number2,  R.drawable.ic_number3};
    String[] thirdpartySites = {"Udacity", "JavaRanch", "Coursera"};
    String[] sourceSites = {"Facebook", "Twitter", "LinkedIn"};

    for (int i = 0; i < logos.length && i < thirdpartySites.length &&   i < sourceSites.length; i++) {
        Information current = new Information();
        current.logoId = logos[i];
        current.thirdParty = thirdpartySites[i];
        current.source = sourceSites[i];
        data.add(current);
        }

        return data;
    }




}
```

PhoneAppsDataFragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/logo_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thirdparty_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/source_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thirdparty_name"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)      {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.logo.setImageResource(current.logoId);
    holder.thirdPartyName.setText(current.thirdParty);
    holder.sourceName.setText(current.source);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView thirdPartyName;
    TextView sourceName;
    ImageView logo;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        logo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo_photo);
        thirdPartyName = (TextView)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.thirdparty_name);
        sourceName  = (TextView)   itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_name);

        }
    }
}
```

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/logo_photo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_number1"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/thirdparty_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_photo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/source_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_photo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thirdparty_name"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Information.java

```
class Information {

    int logoId;
    String thirdParty;
    String source;

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.personamanager.org.personamanager" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"   />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**The error log**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.personamanager.org.personamanager, PID:  2317
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke  virtual method 'void     android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widge    t.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime:     at    com.personamanager.org.personamanager.PhoneAppsDataFragment.onCreateView(P honeAppsDataFragment.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.jav a:1078)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(Coordinator Layout.java:610)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayou t.java:677)
```

Comment: custom_row.xml has no RecyclerView.

Comment: Change `View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, container, false);` to `View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout. activity_mail, container, false);`

Comment: I still get the nullPointerException after making this change. The app still crashes.